# How to add the title of the table the date and time of its creation . SQL ?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 CREATE TABLE  USER_SCOTT.TABLES||'DATA AND TIME'||
   AS  
    SELECT *
      FROM USER_HR.MD_TABLES
```

How to add the title of the table the date and time of its creation?

Comment: But why do you want the creation datetime in the table name? You can get that from the table metadata anyway.

Comment: I hope this is just a "learning example". Using such design in production will generate a lot of headache, you should revise your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it directly in oracle, you can use plsql :

```
Declare
v_sysdate VARCHAR2(10) := to_char(SYSDATE ,'MMDDYYYY');
begin
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE USER_SCOTT.TABLES_'||v_sysdate||'    AS  
             SELECT *
             FROM USER_HR.MD_TABLES ';
COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in simple statement. You have to use a pl/sql,
something like that:

```
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table emp_'||to_char(sysdate,'RRRRMMDD')||' as select * from emp';
    END;
```